# change the background-color of every other element

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the background-color of every other element in the following:

```
<div class="dets">
 <div>Simple Layout</div>
 <div>Few Pictures/Links</div>
 <div>Element Uniformity</div>
</div>
```

So the first [Simple Layout] would be white, the second [Few Pictures/Links] would be black, and so on. I have three of these structures nested in some other div elements. I know about the :even,:odd methods, but it doesn't do as expected. It continues through each of the "dets" classes, increasing the index each time. I want odd rows white, even rows black. Is there a way to restart the natural index for each "dets" class? I do not want to use a table.

I am currently using the following jQuery to set the background-color:

```
$(".dets div:odd").css('background-color', 'white');
$(".dets div:even").css('background-color', 'black');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".dets>div:nth-child(odd)").css('background-color', 'white');
$(".dets>div:nth-child(even)").css('background-color', 'black');
```

also you can do it only with css:

```
.dets>div:nth-child(odd){
 background-color:white;
}
.dets>div:nth-child(even){
 background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: The jQuery worked. Didn't try the CSS. Can you explain why the :even,:odd I used did not work as expected please?

Comment: @QuitoGuillermos You should usenth-child before using even and odd keywords. check this link for more information. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use css [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

You can use id instead of class `.dets` to decrease the index time like `#dets`

You can have other selector also you can use that as per your requirement: e.g.

- **tr:nth-child(2n+1)**
  Represents the odd rows of an HTML table.
- **tr:nth-child(odd)**
  Represents the odd rows of an HTML table.
- **tr:nth-child(2n)**
  Represents the even rows of an HTML table.
- **tr:nth-child(even)**
  Represents the even rows of an HTML table.
- **span:nth-child(0n+1)**
  Represents a span element which is the first child of its parent; this is the same as the :first-child selector.
- **span:nth-child(1)**
  Equivalent to the above.
- **span:nth-child(-n+3)**
  Matches if the element is one of the first three children of its parent and also a span.

```css
.dets>div:nth-child(even){
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}

.dets>div:nth-child(odd){
background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="dets">
 <div>Simple Layout</div>
 <div>Few Pictures/Links</div>
 <div>Element Uniformity</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this in css itself by using

> .dets div:nth-child(odd){ 
>   background-color:white;
>   } 
>   .dets div:nth-child(even){ 
>   background-color:black;
>   }